# How to get and view oracle BLOB (Image) data from HDFS to local system?

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I have stored a image file as BLOB in oracle database and transferred the file to HDFS using below Sqoop command -

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname --username -password --m 5 --table table_name  --target-dir '' --split-by id;
```

Now I want to view the image file in my local system. But after transferred the file from HDFS to my local system, I can only able to view some Hexadecimal code, not the image.

I have tried to convert the Hexadecimal code to Base64 String using Java Code. But unsuccessful.

Sample input of the file:

```
47 49 46 38 39 61 00 05 87 02 f7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 33 00 00 66 00 00 99 00 00 cc 00 00 ff 00 2b 00 00 2b 33 00 2b 66 00 2b 99 00 2b cc 00 2b ff 00 55 00 00 55 33 00 55 66 00 55 99 00 55 cc ........
```

Is there any Sqoop command by which I can directly store the BLOB of oracle to HDFS as an image(.jpg/.jpeg)? Or if there any alternative solution?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer can be found here

[Re-parsing Blob data stored in HDFS imported from Oracle by Sqoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214368/re-parsing-blob-data-stored-in-hdfs-imported-from-oracle-by-sqoop)

Essentially parse to a binary format like avro.

Then stream the field to your local system using something like

[How to view an image from blob column in Oracle with JasperReports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272283/how-to-view-an-image-from-blob-column-in-oracle-with-jasperreports)